# Getting to the Taj Mahal from Delhi and back?

Tags: public-transport, india, taxis, new-delhi

http://goindia.about.com/od/populartrainroutes/qt/delhi-agra-trains.htm

Per that link it seems like I just have two options. Catch a train that leaves at 6:15am or catch one that leaves at 7:10am. What if I want to leave at, say, 10am, instead? Are there trains that run like once every 15 minutes or so?

And once I'm at Agra Cantt what's the best way to get to the Taj Mahal? According to Google Maps the Taj Mahal is about 4mi away from Agra Cantt. That's a walkable distance but in lieu of knowing how much walking I'd want to do at the Taj Mahal I think I'd prefer to conserve my energy. Maybe taxis loiter around at Agra Cantt for passengers as they do at airports? And if they loiter around there do they also loiter around at the Taj Mahal?

Comment: Walking the 4 miles is a bad idea. Will be generally hot (unless in the winter obv.) and you will be swarmed by people wanting to "take you on a ride"! Friendly piece of advice, try to travel with company and not alone if at all possible in northern India. I find that this approach helped several of my non-Indian friends travel in the northern states which are notorious for being tourist un-friendly.

Comment: Do you happen to have any sort of access to a car?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are tons of trains running between various stations in Delhi and Agra, just do a search on the [Indian Rail site](http://www.indianrail.gov.in/).  However, Indian Railways doesn't believe in regular schedules or short routes, so most of all of them run on long, weird, multi-day routes, and are consequently liable to be delayed, sometimes hours, sometimes days.  Many trains also do not have anything approaching comfortable seating by Western standards, and are horribly slow because they stop at every cow shed along the way.  Hence your page's recommendation for trains that start in or near Delhi, which are pretty much guaranteed to be on time, and are "superfast" so they get to Agra in a reasonable amount of time (don't expect a bullet train...).

The other option is the bus, there are lots more and they are reasonable point-to-point.  However, they're subject to the crawling horror of Delhi traffic and the no-holds-barred mayhem on the highways, so [I prefer trains when I can](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23776/chennai-to-pune-bus-or-train).

Despite some tough competition, Agra is quite possibly the most tout-infested city in India, you may find yourself wishing for a nice, heavy stick to beat off the "taxi sir" hordes that will accost you on the platform the moment you get off.  Find and use the prepaid taxi stand at Agra Cantt, but on the way back from the Taj, you'll have to hone your bargaining skills.  And if you're seriously considering walking the 4 mi between the two, I can only presume you haven't been to an Indian city yet...