# A must-see in New Delhi for just a 5-6 hours break

Tags: india, layovers, sightseeing, asia, new-delhi

I'll have just a five or six hours break between flights at Indira Gandhi International Airport. Is there any place or places in New Delhi that is:

- considered a must-see for someone, who is visiting this city for the first time,
- is reachable from the airport in given 5-6 hour period using taxi or other means of transportation.

If there is anything matching above, then can someone provide transportation guidances for that place or places?

**Edit**: *Seems, that I didn't provided the most important idea, that these flights will be domestic, so I can both postpone return flight by an hour or two and that security etc. should be less time-consuming.*

Comment: India gate I assume...

Comment: Taxi will always take more time because of lot of traffic, the best bet is Reliance Metro, cost around 100rs, less than 1.5 dollars one way, 40 minutes commute, and every 40 minutes service.

Comment: Multiple "must see" questions exists around site and most of them are not only off-topic, but also 5-10 points upvoted in addition. Please, explain why is this question different or provide meta explanation to finally explain, whether this kind of questions are or are not on-topic.

Comment: Is 5-6 hours the length of time between the two flight times, or is it the amount of time you've calculated you have in town after taking into account several hours for security, passport control, transport, boarding etc? If it's the former, that sounds really tight

Comment: @user568458 It is time between flights, however you have just realized me, that I didn't provided the most important idea, that these flights will be domestic, so I can both postpone return flight by an hour or two and that security etc. should be less time-consuming.

Comment: Which airlines are you using? Terminal 1 is not connected to the Metro, which will complicate any travel plans greatly.

Comment: You can have a look at [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69052/10-hour-layover-in-delhi-del-is-ist-possible-to-go-sightseeing/69059#69059) also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what your interest really is. New Delhi has quite a lot to offer to foreigners who are looking for something different when they travel. When i travelled to India I wanted something completely different from how it is in Europe - mainly cuisine. I would recommend a couple of places:

1) [Qutub Minar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qutb_Minar) - a really tall brick minaret which is lovely to visit. It is also a UNESCO world heritage site. For directions of how to get there, Rome2Rio has an answer:

https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Delhi-Airport-DEL/Qutub-Minar

2) [Chandni Chowk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandni_Chowk) - A really really crowded place in the heart of the city. There are just too many people around you and more number of shops. And you get all varieties of Indian cuisine. I should warn you that some of them are really spicy and might not go well with people of European origin but i had a wonderful experience tasting some of the dishes made with traditional Indian ingredients. You can use the [metro](http://delhimetrorail.info/igi-airport-delhi-metro-station-to-chandni-chowk-delhi-metro-station) to get there.

Other places include the India Gate, Lotus tempel, a Red Fort (which is also quite popular), and there is a [Rail musuem](http://www.delhitourism.gov.in/delhitourism/entertainment/national_rail_museum.jsp) which was also something that I liked.

Comment: Please do not trust Rome2Rio's taxi travel time estimates - there is *zero* possibility that you could get to Qutub Minar from the airport in 15 minutes anytime during its opening hours.